# adding placeholder to jqueryui combobox

Tags: jquery, placeholder, attr

I am trying to add placeholder to combobox from 
[here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

This is what I tried but I am unable to see placeholder in combobox. Any suggestions please.

```
$("#SelectedGroup").attr("placeholder", "Your Text Here");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .custom-combobox-input selector

```
$('.custom-combobox-input').attr("placeholder", "Your Text Here");
```

working example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5ynZ/)